# Error Using Facebook Login With Parse Server

Tags: ios, facebook, mongodb, heroku, parse-server

I'm one of the many users migrating off of Parse and onto Heroku (w/ MongoLab sandbox), using https://parse.com/docs/server/guide as a guide.

Things were going fine with the migration (objects can be created / retrieved via REST commands on the remote repo) until I tried using (iOS) Facebook login.

The method:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: ... ]
```

which had been working when Parse hosted, now returns the following error:

```
[Error]: Facebook auth is invalid for this user. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)
```

---

Note: the only change to my (previously working) iOS code is to point the Parse server to my new, manually-hosted repo, as shown below:

```
 let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "<*APP ID*>"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "<*CLIENT KEY*>"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://<*HEROKU APP ID*>.herokuapp.com/parse"
    })

 Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

& the only modification to the open source Parse Server code (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) is substituting the configuration to match my Parse / mongo identification:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI:     'mongodb://<*UNIUQUE ID*>' || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: '<*PARSE APP ID*>',
  masterKey: '<*PARSE MASTER KEY*>'
});
```

Answer (score 9):

you need to add the key facebookAppIds which contains an array of valid facebook app ids, this is mentioned [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#basic-options) in the docs.

alternatively, add the  FACEBOOK_APP_ID key as referenced [here] (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/82)

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton for pointing that out. Strangely, however, I'm getting the same error even after this line is included and pushed to the server --> facebookAppIds: ['<*fifteen digit facebook app id code*>']

Comment: In this [guide](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide#migrating), I read the following:   
**Allow FB auth - This is available in Parse Server if a Facebook App ID is configured.**
  
Not sure if by "This is available" they mean that allowing Facebook Auth is a boolean config setting that you need to turn on or if it's supposed to turn on automatically if the facebookAppIds array is set. I would assume the latter.

Comment: I ran across another possibility in the Parse Server [issues](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/82). You can also add a: FACEBOOK_APP_ID environment variable. However, there's currently a [bug] (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/104) where you can't change any data related to the PFUser when its created via FB login.

Comment: That worked! I'm now logged in. This may be obvious to other users, but you have to push the ID as an integer, not a string: heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=**<FacebookID>**
 (Do not put quoes around the ID).

Comment: I'm now getting a myriad of other issues when I try to actually use the app with Parse Server, but I'll create a separate thread for those. I guess with my rep level, I can't mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @JacobKyle there's a known bug with FB login. Parse staff are looking into it [link] (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/104)

Comment: the issue in my comment above has been fixed.

Comment: I also had to allow all class level permissions on the User class, specifically "Add Field"

Comment: This is very important as @Ryan mentioned, you have to pick "Add Field" from the _User class level permission!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you already had or tried this already but I was in a very similar situation as you and what fixed it for me was this:

In **AppDelegate.swift**, the `ParseClientConfiguration` must be initialized **BEFORE** the Parse Facebook Utils initialization in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
...

// *** Initialize Parse. ***
let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
    (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = appKey;
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = clientKey;
    ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = serverURL;
});

Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config);

// *NOTE: Putting the following line after after Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config) fixed the issue
// After this change, the user is no longer nil and does not print "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.". Instead, it executes the `if let user = user` block
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

...
```

Hope this helps at least somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Parse Server running in Back4app.
The solution was to add the Facebook App Id on the Back4app platform.